# Change position of imageView in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, uiimageview

I'd like to change the position of the default imageView in the UITableViewCell (cell.imageView...). Is it possible to do that or do I have to create a new one?

Comment: I guess the best way to do that is customizing UITableViewCell.

Comment: Ok. I created an imageView in the UITableViewCell Subclass. How can I add it to the custom UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new image view in this way:

```
    let iconImageView = UIImageView()
    iconImageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)
    iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "image_name")

    // you have to add the imageview to the content view of the cell 
    contentView.addSubview(iconImageView)
```

Comment: All in the `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` function?

Comment: Ok. Can I controll in which cell the image is set? I don't like to set it in all cells.

Comment: This will not be a full tutorial on iOS programming. You asked a question and received the answer. Right?

Comment: I asked if it's possible to change the position of the default imageView in a UITableViewCell. If you could answer me the last question I got it completely working and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Ok, I see. No, you can't. My recommendation is to create you'r own custom cell and add the image view like I described.

Comment: Ok I got it. Added the imageView as an subview in the main class via an if statement. I knew that before (how to create an imageView). Just not the name of the view were I have to add the imageView as an subclass. But you got your correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let iconImageView = UIImageView()
    iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")
    cell.addSubview(iconImageView)

    iconImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    iconImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    iconImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.rightAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    iconImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

    return cell
}
```